# scrap Cdn-cgi email protecton

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, cgi, protected

When I'm trying to scrap https://www.kw.com/agent/UPA-6904130219335225344-3 email, I'm a facing a problem. It showing [email protected].

How I can I solve this problem?

```
import requests as rq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

headers = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
       "referer": "https://www.kw.com/","Cookie": "AWSALBCORS=+zJ8cI5SlUQSmSyZe9oowBrLJG26sqwO0IeWt1REISJhvdWfy3/YYfWgi32NgACJQv0K/QVwJoFAYnmOTgkWT/OihI7yH1M1kT+5IqLYyUjIYn1AyBPsN2JCO9dO"}

url = 'https://www.kw.com/agent/UPA-6904130219335225344-3'
html = rq.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = bs(html.text, 'html.parser')

email = soup.find('a', class_="AgentInformation__factBody")
print(email)
```

and output

```
<a aria-label="Agent E-mail" class="AgentInformation__factBody" href="/cdn-cgi/l/email-protection#c7a4a6aba2a587a6a4b5a2a2a5b5a8b3afa2b5b4b5a2a6abb3bee9a4a8aa" type="button"><span class="__cf_email__" data-cfemail="5734363b3235173634253232352538233f3225242532363b232e7934383a">[email protected]</span></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Email is protected by CDN. To pull the email you can use an automation tool something like selenium with bs4.

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))#,options=options

driver.get('https://www.kw.com/agent/UPA-6904130219335225344-3')
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(3)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

email = soup.find('a', class_="AgentInformation__factBody")
print(email.text)
```

**Output:**

```
caleb@acreebrothersrealty.com
```